# How to synchronize read and write in the pipe in C?

Tags: c, pipe

Complete C beginner here.
I am trying to write some strings from the child process and read the strings in the parent process. But it looks like I haven't implemented the read and write properly. So my parent just reads the first string it gets. Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Function declaration */
bool isNumeric(char* str);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Check if input is recieved
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Input not received!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Check if the input is an int
    if (isNumeric(argv[1]) == 0) {
        printf("Input is not an Integer!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize pipe
    int      fd[2];
    pid_t    childpid;

    pipe(fd);
    childpid = fork();

    if (childpid == -1) {
        printf("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (childpid > 0) {
            char string[100];
            close(fd[1]);
            printf("PARENT START\n");
            while (read(fd[0], string, sizeof(string)) > 0) {
                    printf("%s\n", string);
            }
            printf("PARENT END\n");
            close(fd[0]);
    }
    else {
            close(fd[0]);
            char string[100];
            string[0] = '\0';
            printf("CHILD START\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    sprintf(string, "%d", i);
                    write(fd[1], string, strlen(string)+1);
            }
            printf("CHILD END\n");
            close(fd[1]);
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

The output is just

```
PARENT START
CHILD START
CHILD END
0
PARENT END
```

My expected output is

```
PARENT START
CHILD START
CHILD END
0
1
2
3
4
PARENT END
```

I spent hours trying to synchronize the process, but I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your parent is likely receiving all the strings in one `read`. But you are terminating each `write` in the child with a NUL. So in the case that the parent receives all the child input in one go there will be multiple strings in the parent `string` buffer. Print out the return value of the `read` to verify how much data is actually read.

Comment: You must not assume that there will be a 1-1 relationship between the number of writes and reads into a pipe. That is, one process may write 10 things into the pipe before the other side reads and when the read happens it can get all of the 10 writes.

Answer (score 1):

You ignore the return value of `read`, so the call to `printf` stops at the first zero byte. You send the messages delimited by zero bytes. Where's the code to find the zero bytes in the received data and extract the messages from the pipe?

You have code to send a message. It separates the messages with a terminating zero byte. Where's the code to receive a message, searching the incoming stream of data for zero bytes and passing on the data prior to it as a message?

Here's some ugly, inefficient code to receive a message. It checks the incoming stream of bytes for the terminating zero byte. It returns `0` on end of file, negative on error and `1` on success.:

```
int recvMessage (int fd, char* buf, int len)
{
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int r = read(fd, buf, 1);
        if (r <= 0) // pipe closed or error
            return r;
        if (*buf == 0) // we received a terminating zero byte
            return 1;
        buf++;
        len--;
    }
    return -2; // message larger than buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Five things you need to learn:

- `sizeof(string)` doesn't return the length of a string, much less one you haven't read in yet! It always returns 100 in this case.
- `write` is not guaranteed to write the number of bytes provided as its third argument. You need to call `write` repeatedly until the entire buffer you want to write has been written.
- `read` is not guaranteed to read the number of bytes provided as its third argument. You need to call `read` repeatedly until you've read the desired number of bytes.
- In this case, you don't want to read a specific number of bytes. You want to read until one of the character you've read is a NUL.
- Unless you pass `1` for `read`'s third parameter, you might end up reading too much. This is not a problem; you just need to factor that in the next time you read.

---

**Writer**

Replace

```c
write(fd[1], string, strlen(string)+1);
```

with

```c
char *p = string;
size_t n = strlen(string) + 1;
while (n > 0) {
   ssize_t rv = write(fd[1], p, n);
   if (rv == -1) {
      perror("write");
      exit(1);
   }

   n -= rv;
   p += rv;
}
```

---

**Reader**

Replace

```c
char string[100];
while (read(fd[0], string, sizeof(string)) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

with

```c
#define BLOCK_SIZE 100
char *string = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
size_t len = 0;

while (1) {
   // Increase the buffer size if necessary.
   if (size < len + BLOCK_SIZE) {
      char *tmp = realloc(string, len + BLOCK_SIZE);
      if (!tmp) {
         perror("realloc");
         exit(1);
      }

      string = tmp;
   }

   // Read from the pipe.
   ssize_t rv = read(fd[0], string+len, BLOCK_SIZE);
   if (rv == -1) {
      perror("read");
      exit(1);
   }

   // Handle EOF
   if (rv == 0)
      break;

   len += rv;

   // Check if we've received a message (or even more than one).
   while (1) {
      for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i) {
         if (!string[i]) {
            // Handle a message.
            ...

            len -= i+1;
            memmove(string, string+i+1, len);
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}

// Handle a partial message.
if (len) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF");
   exit(1);
}

free(string);
```

Comment: It's quite right that `sizeof(string)` does not return a string length.  However, it is a perfectly reasonable thing for the OP to pass as the third argument to `read()`.  At least in a general sense.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I didn't say otherwise, but what you say it's true. If you had a fixed size array buffer, you'd want `sizeof(string)` minus what you've already read in the previous read. See third and fifth bullets.